# Tensorflow Python 3.7 when

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently support for tensorflow is only Python <=3.6

What timeline for tensorflow support for Python 3.7 ?

So that I know if i uninstall Python 3.7  or wait.

Comment: Why would anyone here know? Why don't you ask the Tensorflow dev team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.7 appears to be official now, ("final release" on June 27th).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [information](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.1), I would say that tensorflow 1.13 already supports Python 3.7.